# jquery selector for "#id_article-DYNAMIC_NUMBER-media_description_DYNAMIC_CHAR"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've many elements on the page whose ID looks like

```
id_article-     Number    -media_description     _en
^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^
Fixed Prefix   Variable       Fixed part         Variable
                Number                           part
```

Ex:

```
id_article-0-media_description_en
```

where `0` and `en` are dynamic. `0` can be 1, 2, 3, 4.. and `en` can be `de`, `es` etc

```
$("[id^='id_article-0-media_description']").each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    var lang = this.id.split('_').pop();
    if($.trim($el.val())) {
        var a = '#tab_id_article-0-media_description_' + lang;
        $('a[href="' + a + '"]').css('background', 'green');
    }
});
```

this works. but not dynamic enough, because `id_article-`**0**`-media_description`, the `0` can be 1, 2, 3, .....

I tried with:

```
$("[id^='id_article']").each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    var lang = this.id.split('_').pop();
    var id = this.id.split('-')[1]; // <----
    if ($.trim($el.val())) {
        var a = '#tab_id_article-'+id+'-media_description_' + lang;
        $('a[href="' + a + '"]').css('background', 'green');
    }
});
```

but it is not working. I think the key to the problem is, I should do:

```
$("[id^='id_article-0-media_description_en']").each(function () {
    // ...
});
```

how can I make this selector generic?

**UPDATED** sorry, i forgot to mention that the id has another dynamic part at  the end of it, i.e. language part

Comment: Why not use a common class? This is *exactly* what they are for.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan tags are generated dynamically and cannot control them

Comment: Regex is not possibile in CSS selectors, use a class instead or a custom attribute

Comment: Could you not use a more generic selector then, something like `#container .somediv > div` where the last `div` is the `id_article-X` element you're trying to loop over.

Comment: "i tried with [...] but it's not working" - define: "not working".

Comment: @Jamiec not selecting (obvious enough from the question)

Comment: You would be surprised how often people say "not working" and what they have is a load of javascript errors in the console entirely unrelated to their jQuery selectors

Comment: @Jamiec you are absolutely right

Comment: Please add comment here why this question should be reopened, isn't this dupe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Use Starts with with combination of ends with attribute selector.</strike>

```
$("[id^='id_article-'][id$='-media_description']").each(function () {
```

---

You can also use `filter` with regex if there are other elements in DOM which satisfies both the prefix and suffix conditions but does not contain digit in between them.

```
var regex = /^id_article-\d+-media_description_[a-z]{2}$/;

// Narrow down elements by using attribute starts with and ends with selector
var allEls = $("[id^='id_article-']").filter(function () {

    // filter the elements that passes the regex pattern
    return regex.test($(this).attr('id'));
}).each(// Further code
```

Comment: Is the AND operator assumed here? I don't know anything about regex, just logically there has to be an AND.

Comment: @Tushar thanks, but I forgot one more thing, there is `_en` at the end of the id which is also dynamic. I updated my question!

Comment: @doniyor Assuming the last **two** words represent the language, I've used `[a-z]{2}` in the regex. You can update this according to your need. Check updated answer.

Comment: @Tushar your second selector doesnot work now, because of `[id$='-media_description']`  which has missing language part, right?

Comment: Welcome @doniyor. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You *really* should be using a class for this.

One work-around would be to match all elements with an `id` that starts with `[id^='id_article']`, and then determine whether it also contains a number followed by `-media_description_(en|es|de)` using the regular expression:

```
/^id_article-\d+-media_description_(en|es|de)$/
```

```js
$("[id^='id_article']").each(function () {
  if (this.id.match(/^id_article-\d+-media_description_(en|es|de)$/)) {
    // It's a match
    $(this).css('color', '#f00');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="id_article-0-media_description_en">0 (en)</div>
<div id="id_article-1-media_description_de">1 (de)</div>
<div id="id_article-333-media_description_es">333 (es)</div>
<div id="id_article-NAN-media_description">NaN</div>
```

Comment: Ends with attribute value selector should also be used with Starts with to narrow down elements

Comment: @Tushar It *really* doesn't matter. The results would be exactly the same. If anything, a single attribute selector is going to be faster, and the regex check is cheap. The performance difference would be negligible.